# Win32 - does the CRITICAL_SECTION struct must have a specific (4/8 byte) alignment?

Tags: windows, alignment, deadlock, critical-section

I am working on a project which is using 1 byte alignment by default, including in places that use the CRITICAL_SECTION struct. I am investigating a certain deadlock and I can see that the data in the CRITICAL_SECTION struct which is causing the trouble is invalid .. can the alignment be the trouble ? (I can also see that for this specific CRITICAL_SECTION indeed the alignment is 1 (odd address) ..)

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: No, the Windows headers specify alignment.

Comment: Are you talking about alignment within the struct, or alignment of the struct itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows header files [require `/Zp8` packing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/22/9560726.aspx). You must respect the packing specified by the header file.

Comment: David - both. In the case I described for example I can see that both the struct itself and its LockCount member have an alignment of 1

Comment: Thanks Raymond, still I would be glad to also know if anyone experienced a problem due to a non-supported alignment of the CRITICAL_SECTION struct in specific, to be more assured that this is also my problem ...

Comment: @Amit Whether this is a likely cause will depend on which version of Windows and which processor architecture you are using.

Comment: About architecture it is basically a x64 processor but the application is 32 bit.

Comment: I didn't know the answer but I decided to search on SO. (You could've done that too.) [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5178914/902497) says that unaligned accesses that cross a cache line boundary are not atomic on certain CPU families.

Comment: Thanks Raymond.. this doesn't address Critical Sections specifically .. but I guess it's necessary that somewhere in its guts the functions like EnterCriticalSection etc use some atomic instruction like that ..