# Is AtomicCmpExchange reliable on all platforms?

Tags: delphi

I can't find the implementation of `AtomicCmpExchange` (seems to be hidden), so I don't know what it does.

Is `AtomicCmpExchange` reliable on all platforms? How is it implemented internally? Does it use something like a critical section?

I have this scenario :

MainThread:

```
Target := 1;
```

Thread1:

```
x := AtomicCmpExchange(Target, 0, 0);
```

Thread2:

```
Target := 2;
```

Thread3:

```
Target := 3;
```

Will `x` always be an integer 1, 2 or 3, or could it be something else? I mean, even if the `AtomicCmpExchange(Target, 0, 0)` failed to exchange the value, does it return a "valid" integer (I mean, not a half-read integer, for exemple if another thread has already started to half write of the value)?

I want to avoid using a critical section, I need maximum speed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`AtomicCmpExchange` is what is known as an [*intrinsic routine*, or a *standard function*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines). It is intrinsically known to the compiler and may or may not have a visible implementation. For example, `Writeln` is a standard function, but you won't find a single implementation for it. The compiler breaks it up into multiple calls to lower-level functions in System.pas. Some standard functions, such as `Inc()` and `Dec()` don't have any implementation in System.pas. The compiler will generate machine instructions which amount to simple `INC` or `DEC` instructions.

Like `Inc()` or `Dec()`, `AtomicCmpExchange()` is implemented using whatever code is needed for a given platform. It will generate inline instructions. For x86/x64 it will generate a `CMPXCHG` instruction (along with whatever setup is necessary to get variables/values into the registers). For ARM it will generate a few more instructions around the `LDREX` and `STREX` instructions.

So the direct answer to your question is that even calling into assembly code, you cannot get much more efficient than using that standard function along with others such as `AtomicIncrement`, `AtomicDecrement`, and `AtomicExchange`.

Comment: Yes, it will always return a valid integer. If the value of the target matches the comparand, the value is swapped and the return value is the target's previous value. If the target doesn't match, then the value is returned. All of this is done atomically, which means it is guaranteed to complete without any worry of intermediate states messing it up.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the variables must be aligned

Comment: Microsoft says that alignment is required (for both x86 and x64) but Intel seems to disagree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415256/alignment-requirements-for-atomic-x86-instructions

Comment: @Alexandre And what about the mobile targets which run on ARM? Even on Intel there are performance reasons that mean aligned access is preferable.

Comment: @David Hefferman: So the correct answer is:
- For x86 and x64 alignment is preferred but not mandatory

Comment: @Alexandre The question explicitly states interest in "all platforms". Different platforms have different requirements. It's true that x86 and x64 `LOCK` allows you to straddle cache lines, at the cost of performance. But the requirements on ARM are different.