# Why misaligned access to locked memory read intermediate value on intel cpu?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, intel, memory-alignment

I'm studying misaligned memory access now.

According to [intel document](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671190), Lock instruction use bus-lock to the memory across two cache-line. (I have a 'core i7' cpu.)

**9.1.2 Bus Locking**

> Intel 64 and IA-32 processors provide a LOCK# signal that is asserted automatically during certain critical memory operations to lock the system bus or equivalent link. Assertion of this signal is called a bus lock. While this output signal is asserted, requests from other processors or bus agents for control of the bus are blocked. Software can specify other occasions when the LOCK semantics are to be followed by prepending the LOCK prefix to an instruction.

**9.1.2.2 Software Controlled Bus Locking**

> The integrity of a bus lock is not affected by the alignment of the memory field. The LOCK semantics are followed for as many bus cycles as necessary to update the entire operand.

> Locked operations are atomic with respect to all other memory operations and all externally visible events. Only instruction fetch and page table accesses can pass locked instructions. Locked instructions can be used to synchronize data written by one processor and read by another processor.

> For the P6 family processors, locked operations serialize all outstanding load and store operations (that is, wait for them to complete). This rule is also true for the Pentium 4 and Intel Xeon processors, with one exception. Load operations that reference weakly ordered memory types (such as the WC memory type) may not be serialized.

I made multi-thread test code as below, And the result is not as I expected.

I expect that using InterlockedCompareExchange(using Lock cmpxchg instruction) make the bus locked, so reading the value(using mov instruction) is also must be serialized. But It read intermediate value such as 0xFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAA and 0xAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFF.

Can you explain why? Do I misunderstand bus lock or anything else?

**[test summary]**
**Read and write to the memory address which is across two cache-line.**

thread1: CompareAndExchange to NUM1(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)

thread2: CompareAndExchange NUM2(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

thread3: read and check whether the value is not NUM1 and NUM2.

result:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>

constexpr unsigned __int64 NUM1 = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
constexpr unsigned __int64 NUM2 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

inline bool IsGarbageValue(unsigned __int64 value)
{
  return (value != NUM1 && value != NUM2);
}

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct alignas(64) TestValue
{
  char pad[60];
  unsigned __int64 value;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
  TestValue test;
  test.value = NUM1;
  std::thread t1([&test]()
    {
      while (1)
      {
        auto org = InterlockedCompareExchange(&test.value, NUM1, NUM2);
      }
    });

  std::thread t2([&test]()
    {
      while (1)
      {
        auto org = InterlockedCompareExchange(&test.value, NUM2, NUM1);
      }
    });

  std::thread t3([&test]()
    {
      while (1)
      {
        if (::IsGarbageValue(test.value))
        {
          std::cout << std::hex << test.value << std::endl;
        }
      }
    });
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
}
```

Comment: @user7860670 doesn't `alignas(64)` and `char pad[60]` guarantee 32-bit boundary alignment?

Comment: @user7860670 they're actually using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange64, Microsoft in their infinite wisdom have overloaded `InterlockedCompareExchange` but don't seem to have put that in their documentation

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not sure that 60 is a multiple of 32 (or actually 64)

Comment: Use the return value of `InterlockedCompareExchange`; that's the old value of the memory location.  Not some other pure load that isn't and can't be `lock`ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so reading the value(using mov instruction) is also must be serialized

A cache-line split load uop needs two separate cache accesses in separate cycles to get both parts of the value.

Intel load execution units have some number of split-load buffers to allow multiple split loads to be in-flight at once; a cache line split can only be detected after address-generation, and the CPU is optimized for the non-split case.  So the scheduler could have sent it another load uop in the next cycle.  Also, one or the other of the cache lines might not be valid in cache, in which case it'll be many cycles before the other half arrives.  (And the execution unit can run other load uops in the meantime.)

Anyway, the bus-lock required for a split `lock` means that neither part of a plain load can happen during a `lock cmpxchg`, but nothing stops a `lock cmpxchg` from happening between the pieces of a non-atomic load.  **The "serialization" you're talking about is on individual accesses to cache, not whole instructions.**

There's no way to make a misaligned pure-load atomic on x86 (except with transactional memory (RTM) which is only supported on a few CPUs; Intel keeps disabling it with microcode updates after finding bugs or vulnerabilities in it or caused by it, so OSes may also disable it.)  The `lock` prefix doesn't apply to `mov`, only to some memory-destination RMW instructions.

To test atomicity of misaligned `lock`ed operations, **test the return value of `InterlockedCompareExchange`** - that gives you the old value of the location as seen by the CAS attempt, whether it succeeds or fails. i.e. it's the load side of the atomic RMW.  ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ttk2z1ws(v=vs.85)))

Have the two writer threads do `::IsGarbageValue(org)` and remove the third thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, Is it right that bus-lock prevent read the memory(pure-load using `mov`)? Is it right that I explain the reason that my test program show '0xAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFF' like below? 1. thread1 write '0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' 2. thread3 can not access the memory while thread1 write the value because of bus-lock. 3. after thread1's writing done, thread3 read the value of higher part(0xAAAAAAAA) from cacheline1. 4. thread2 write '0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'. 5. thread3 read the value of lower part(0xFFFFFFFF) from chacheline2. 6. finally thread3 read '0xAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFF'

Comment: @이종명 - that's correct.  I'd guess that the first half of the load to request a value from memory is actually the lower-address one, the one containing the first byte of the qword, i.e. the one in the cache line containing the byte at the address calculated by the address math, since wider integers are addressed by their low byte.  But same difference.  (Now I'm curious to try a writer that does `u64 tmp = 0;` `tmp += 0x100000001` / `shared.exchange(tmp)` so both halves are written with an increasing counter, and the reader can see which half was higher.)

Comment: @이종명: Indeed, https://godbolt.org/z/P66qfWKeW is a test program that does that.  I get results like `12600000125` and `1300000012f`, where the high half saw one modification later than the low half.  IDK why it doesn't print any output on Godbolt even when I made it exit cleanly after 1 second instead of timeout; it ran fine locally on my Linux desktop.  (It should be portable to MSVC except for the `__attribute__((packed))`; I should have used `aligned_alloc` or just violated strict-aliasing as well by taking a pointer into the middle of an aligned `char`  array.)

Answer (score 4):

`auto org = InterlockedCompareExchange(&test.value, NUMa, NUMb)` reads and writes the values and guarantees the atomicity of the read and write operations.

However, `if (::IsGarbageValue(test.value))` does not guarantee the atomicity of the read operation.

So, your `t1` and `t2` are working just fine, but your `t3` is just reading garbage.

The solution is, as Peter Cordes writes in a comment: Have the two writer threads do `IsGarbageValue(org)` and remove the third thread.

Comment: Furthermore, note that your `std::cout << test.value` does not print the value that was found to be garbage; it prints some other value.  Because the value has changed between the `if()` and the `std::cout <<`.

Comment: To usefully test for atomicity of misaligned `lock`ed operations, test the return value of `InterlockedCompareExchange` - that gives you the old value of the location as seen by the CAS attempt, whether it succeeds or fails.  i.e. it's the load side of the atomic RMW.  So have the two writer threads do `IsGarbageValue(org)` and remove the third thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I missed some information. My compiler optimized the code and `test.value` is moved to register(e.g. rax) at first. Thus, `if()` and `std::cout <<` use the register, same value. I'm sorry for not enough information on my question.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [InterlockedCompareExchange64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange64) states:

> The variables for this function must be aligned on a 64-bit boundary; otherwise, this function will behave unpredictably on multiprocessor x86 systems and any non-x86 systems.

By not passing an aligned argument you're not following the requirements of the function so there's no guarantee it'll be atomic.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178914/5494370

Comment: Interesting quirk of MS's docs, but that's not an actual problem. 32-bit mode `lock cmpxchg8b` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg8b:cmpxchg16b) or 64-bit mode `lock cmpxchg qword` don't require alignment for correctness, they're just *very* slow in the cache-line split case (compared to when they can just delay responding to MESI requests for a single cache line), and it's a system-wide slowdown.  Interestingly, `lock cmpxchg16b` (InterlockedCompareExchange128) does require 16-byte alignment: it's guaranteed to #GP(0) fault. (MS says "behave unpredictably on x64".)

Comment: @PeterCordes not according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415256/alignment-requirements-for-atomic-x86-instructions-vs-mss-interlockedcompareex/5178914#5178914 from reading the comments, the lock itself works with unaligned accesses but it won't work with non-locked accesses like the OP expects. Running their code with an aligned variable does produce the expected output

Comment: re: your edit: the answer you linked is incorrect, please downvote it more, see comments under it, and the other answers. Those quotes are about atomicity of pure-loads and pure-stores, which is indeed only guaranteed within a cache line (Intel) or within a qword (AMD) for cacheable accesses. That's why the pure-load in `::IsGarbageValue(test.value)` fails, because it's *not* using `lock cmpxchg`.  Mackie Messer's answer on that question is the relevant one for InterlockedCompareExchange64 itself.  Mike Nakis's answer is the correct one to this question.

Comment: Yes, of course aligning it makes tearing impossible.  Their code also has data-race UB on `test.value` since they do a pure-C++ read of it while other threads are writing it.  Compilers could hoist the check out of the loop, so it's only a valid test if they disable optimization.  (To fix that, use `std::atomic_ref` to do a `.load()`, or at least `volatile`.)

Comment: The actual test would be to test the return value of `InterlockedCompareExchange` - that gives you the old value of the location as seen by the CAS attempt, whether it succeeds or fails.  i.e. it's the load side of the atomic RMW.

Comment: @PeterCordes 'Quirk'  Nicely put.