# C# atomicity: assignment of int vs. long on x64 platform

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, pointers, thread-safety

I am looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278(VS.71).aspx, which said read and write of int is atomic, while read and write of long may not be. Is that really true for 64 bit platform? Isn't it IntPtr.Size == 64 bit or long? Am I missing something or the language specs are not full enough?

More thoughts here as well:
http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/beware-assignment-atomic-assignment/

Comment: Check out this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881820/interlockedexchange-and-memory-alignment - alignment is important.

Comment: Are you working with C# 1.0 and .NET 1.1? If not, then you should probably ignore ancient documents like that. The specification is at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I just googled it. Do you think C# language specification changes much from version to version of .NET?

Comment: The C# language specification changes between versions of C#. It has nothing to do with .NET versions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`long` is an atomic write on CPUs **and** platforms that have 64-bit words.  e.g. if you run a 32-bit .NET application on a 64-bit computer, writes to `long` will *not* be atomic.

Mind you, atomicity is almost pointless if you can't make sure the compiler doesn't optimize access to that type of variable.  e.g. you can't decorate a `long` field with `volatile`.

> Operations on 64-bit fields are guaranteed to be atomic only in a 64-bit runtime environment

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

> if you are running C# code on a 64 bit operating system in a 64 bit version of the CLR then reads and writes of 64 bit doubles and long integers are also guaranteed to be atomic

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two.aspx

Comment: Ah! That's the catch. Thanks! What's the source of this info?

Comment: @Schultz9999 I've added some quotes and references detailing the same information.

Comment: "long is an atomic write on CPUs and platforms that have 64-bit words" - that's not entirely true and there may be exceptions. 1. AFAIK there's no guarantee that the Complier would never split the 64-bit mov into two 32-bit ones. The C# spec does not mandate atomicity of 64-bit operations. 2. Even the CPU itself does not guarantee atomicity, for example if the two 32-bit parts are split across different cache lines. These are quite rare exceptions but they should be considered as well.

Comment: @valiano on a 32-bit processor or a 32-bit target that is true, but not on a 64-bit processor targeting a 64-bit processor

Comment: Thanks @PeterRitchie - I was looking at the C# spec, but missed the fact that the CLI spec assures 64-bit accesses are atomic (where native int is 64-bit), as mentioned in the quoted blog post. Cheers

Comment:  yeah @valiano, the whole story is across a few specs, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

That's the documentation for VS2003 which corresponds to .NET Framework 1.1, which was only available in a 32-bit flavour (ignoring the very niche IA-64 editions for now).

The .NET Framework 2.0 introduced the x64 edition, where (as long as you're running in 64-bit mode) then certain (but not all) Int64 operations will be atomic.

Of course, if you want to be certain, use the `Interlocked` class.